# how to easily make complex Euler/Venn diagrams in R?

Tags: r

From my microarray data I have selected three subsets of probes. I would like to display these subsets as a Euler diagram to visualize the overlaps, but am struggling with inputting the combinations into Eulerr. All three subsets need to be nested within the full set of probes; one subset is fully contained within another, and the third overlaps with the other two. Is there a package into which I could feed the vectors of probe names and let it determine the overlaps for me? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in R, consider using the UpsetR library.  It doesn't make Venn diagrams but it helps to visualize overlaps between any number of groups.

[http://gehlenborglab.org/research/projects/upsetr/#:~:text=UpSetR%20is%20an%20R%20package,based%20on%20groupings%20and%20queries](http://gehlenborglab.org/research/projects/upsetr/#:%7E:text=UpSetR%20is%20an%20R%20package,based%20on%20groupings%20and%20queries).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider different ways of using the `venneuler` package. I'm not super thrilled with its usability (or with the accuracy of the overlaps), but you can get it to make custom Venn diagrams.

[Here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-May/239639.html) is a thread with some suggestions along these lines.

Below is some sample R code that I slightly modified from an old project that I used to make a 3-category Venn diagram.

I didn't run this to make sure that it works because of an irritating Java dependency issue on my OSX laptop that I don't feel like fixing right now, but as long as you have a JDK on your machine and can install the packages it *should* work.

```
# note irritating rJava dependency of venneuler
library(plotrix)
library(venneuler)

#A-B sharing: 200414
#B-C sharing: 17561
#A-C sharing: 16764
#All share 14201

# get coordinates for circles- replace as needed
# this function is supposed to plot stuff, but doesn't actually
ven = venneuler(c(C=48147-17561-16764+14201, 
                  B=347181-17561-200414+14201, 
                  A=325971-200414-16764+14201, 
                  "C&B"=17561, "B&A"=200414, "C&A"=16764, "A&B&C"=14201))

cats = c('A','B','C')

# note- this following only shows up in the .pdf printer, not in the X11 utility plotter
pdf('venn.pdf')
plot(c(-.5,1.5), c(-.5,1.5), type='n', xaxt='n', yaxt='n', bty='n', xlab='', ylab='')
draw.circle(ven$center[1,1], ven$center[1,2], ven$diameters[1],
        col = hsv(1,1,1,.5))
draw.circle(ven$center[2,1], ven$center[2,2], ven$diameters[2], 
            col = hsv(.5,1,1,.5))
draw.circle(ven$center[3,1], ven$center[3,2], ven$diameters[3],
            col = hsv(.1,1,1,.5))

text(ven$center[1,1]+.065, ven$center[1,2], labels=cats[3], cex=1.3)
text(ven$center[2,1], ven$center[2,2]-.2, labels=cats[2], cex=1.3)
text(ven$center[3,1], ven$center[3,2]+.2, labels=cats[1], cex=1.3)

dev.off()
```